# The center of the fundamental group of closed surface

Tags: group-theory, homotopy-theory

$S^g$ is a closed surface with genus $g$, we know that the fundamental group $\pi_1(S^g)=\{a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_g,b_1,\dots,b_g|a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}\dots a_gb_ga_g^{-1}b_g^{-1}=1\}$, how to calculate the center of $\pi_1(S^g)$? I think the center of $\pi_1(S^g)$ is trivial, if $g\ge 2$, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental group is the amalgamated product of free groups, whose centers are trivial, so that its center is trivial, too.

Comment: How to write the fundamental group in the way as the amalgamated product of free groups?

Comment: See the decomposition in Theorem 1.2. here: http://math.nsc.ru/~bogopolski/Articles/decomp.pdf‎.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that these groups are small cancellation (for $g>1$) to prove that their centers are trivial. See the final chapter of Lyndon and Schupp's book *Combinatorial group theory*. Alternatively, you can use the fact that they are torsion-free hyperbolic (a generalisation of small cancellation). See Bridson and Haefliger's book *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature*. However, I am sure that there are many simpler, and more direct, ways.

An alternative method would be to use the fact that this is a one-relator group. See [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/231274/10513) on an (essentially identical) question.